# Python Prime functions

Tags: python

I'm completely new to this whole coding gig, and I'm just trying to learn the basics. Currently, I'm attempting t create a prime function that indicates whether an input is prime. I checked past posts and nobody approached the problem in a similar fashion as I did, so I have no precedent. I would really appreciate it if somebody could inform me why my code isn't functioning as desired.

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x==0 or x==1:
            return False  
    for n in range(2,x-1):
        if "." not in str(int(x/n)): 
            return True 
        else:
            return False
```

I thought that I could just create a loop to determine if any numbers preceding x are factors and if not then the number would be prime because all outputs would contain decimals.

Comment: Just use the modulo operator, `%`, not that abomination. BTW, the result of `int` is always an integer, so there can't be a dot in `str(int(whatever))`.

Comment: Also, you cannot return `True` early like that...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very good approach performance-wise.
And also, dividing two integers in Python2 will give you an integer, so no precision point.
In Python3 you will always get a precision point, but if you cast it back to an integer, then you always lose it, just like in Python2.

Answer (score 0):

Before you post anymore questions on basic workings of a programming language, try to find the answer in documentation please.

As I understand it from here: [int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)

> Return an integer object constructed from a number or string x, or return 0 if no arguments are given. If x is a number, it can be a plain integer, a long integer, or a floating point number. **If x is floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero.** If the argument is outside the integer range, the function returns a long object instead.